# Strictly Monotone Sequences of Subsets of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Does every infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contain a strictly monotone sequence? How should I approach this question to prove it? Which arguments should I use?

Comment: If $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is infinite, it contains a subset $\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $a_m=a_n$ iff $m=n$. Show that the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a strictly monotone subsequence. This has been done here before; you should attempt it on your own, but you can find an argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928415/a-question-on-a-proof-that-every-sequence-has-a-monotone-subsequence).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so the set {a<sub>n</sub> } contains distinct elements and we generate a sequence with that set. After that, we pick the strictly increasing or decreasing points of (a<sub>n</sub>)  and generate a monotone subsequence, am I right?

Comment: Actually showing that the sequence *has* a strictly monotone subsequence takes a bit of work, but yes, that’s the basic idea.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott isn't it just the Monotone Subsequence Theorem?

Comment: Yes, if you’ve already proved such a theorem or otherwise have it available to use; if not, you need to prove it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! I guess since we already pick distinct elements, our subsequence is directly strictly monotone.

Comment: You’re welcome!